# Python only writes the key of a dictionary to a csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

The code gets an input of the name and the password from an input, then it converts the username and password to a dictionary

```
dicReg = {username: pw}
```

when I print the dicReg now I get a normal dictinoary.

```
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

now I want to add the dictionary to a csv file, the code runns without any errors

```
with open('data.csv', 'a') as fp:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fp, dicReg)
    writer.writerow(dicReg)
```

but when I open the csv files later, it only showes the key of the dictionary

Example for the output:

```
{'foo': 'bar'}
{'spam': 'eggs'}
```

https://prnt.sc/pawolz

Comment: Here are quite a few examples of using `DictWriter` ( https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/3190/csv.DictWriter ). Looks like you need to iterate over the `dict`.

Comment: Your code writes the value here.

Comment: `I want to add the whole dictionary`. So you want every single key, value pair, in order, to be printed into a single cell in your `.csv` file?

Comment: Yes, as shown on the screenshot https://prnt.sc/pawolz

Comment: question edited

Comment: @DavidD. Perhaps you could improve your question by marking more clearly the input, the corresponding expected output, your code and your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my understanding is that you want the WHOLE dictionary. If you want the entire dictionary represented as a string in a csv file, this is how to achieve that:

```
dicReg = {'foo': 'bar'}

with open('data.csv', 'a') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerow([str(dicReg)])
```

So your file would contain these contents:

```
{'foo':'bar'}
```

Although I would suggest you store something like that in JSON format, it is acheivable in csv as well.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you, the other answers would work aswell but I wanted to make it like this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You only get the dictionary values with `.writerow()`.  To get the keys as a header row, use `.writeheader()`:

```
import csv
dicReg = {'foo':'bar','foo2':'bar2'}
with open('data.csv','w',newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fp,dicReg)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(dicReg)
```

Output:

```
foo,foo2
bar,bar2
```

If instead you want the keys and values as columns, you don't want DictWriter:

```
import csv
dicReg = {'foo':'bar','foo2':'bar2'}
with open('data.csv','w',newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    for k,v in dicReg.items():
        writer.writerow([k,v])
```

Output:

```
foo,bar
foo2,bar2
```

Comment: I want to add the WHOLE dictionary, not separated https://prnt.sc/pawolz

Answer (score 0):

The idea of `csv.DictWriter()` is not to dump a dictionary to a `csv` file, but to write multiple dictionaries to the same tabular structure.
Given this, the `key`s of the dictionary act as a header for your tabular data.

This is clear from the example from the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

```
import csv

with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
```

with output in `names.csv`:

```
first_name,last_name
Baked,Beans
Lovely,Spam
Wonderful,Spam
```

---

## EDIT

If you have an input `dict` that you want to dump to a text file such that you have `<key>,<value>` for each `dict` entry, one way of using this with `csv.DictWriter` is:

```
import csv

data = {'foo': 'bar', 'ping': 'pong'}

with open('data.csv', 'a') as file_obj:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file_obj, fieldnames=['key', 'val'])
    for k, v in data.items():
        writer.writerow({'key': k, 'val': v})
```

the content of `data.csv` will be:

```
foo,bar
ping,pong
```

---

## EDIT 2

If all you want is a string representation of your `dict` in a line, I do not see `csv.DictWriter()` or even `csv` a good fit for the job.
The following code would reproduce your expected output:

```
data = [
   {'foo': 'bar'},
   {'spam': 'eggs'}
]

with open('data.csv', 'a') as file_obj:
    for d in data:
        file_obj.write(str(d) + '\n')
```

and the content of `data.csv` will be:

```
{'foo': 'bar'}
{'spam': 'eggs'}
```

Comment: I want the output to be the WHOLE dict, not separated
https://prnt.sc/pawolz <-- Like this

Comment: @DavidD. It looks to me that I answered the question as written. If you are after something alse, as your comment seems to indicate, then perhaps you should reword your question accordingly, including the expected output (perhaps with a couple more examples).

Comment: It works but it is still not what I need, I updated the question with an example

Comment: @DavidD. see `EDIT 2`